# Добавление кнопки на окно

Tags: java, button, awt

Создаю окно с некоторой надписью и реакцией на нажатие клавиш(отображение нажатых символов на окне). Помогите пожулуйста создать кнопку на этом же окне, по каждому нажатию на которую, будет меняться цвет фона окна.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.EventListener;

public class AppWindow extends Frame 
{
    String kmsg = "It is window";

    public AppWindow()
    {
        addKeyListener(new MyKeyAdapter(this));
        addWindowListener(new MyWindowAdapter());
     }

     public void paint(Graphics g)
     {
         g.drawString(kmsg, 110, 60);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         AppWindow appwin = new AppWindow();
         appwin.setSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
         appwin.setTitle("Blank window");
         appwin.setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

class MyKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter
{
     AppWindow appWindow;
     public MyKeyAdapter(AppWindow appWindow)
     {
        this.appWindow = appWindow;
     }

     public void keyTyped (KeyEvent k)
     {
        appWindow.kmsg += k.getKeyChar();
        appWindow.repaint();
     }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

class MyWindowAdapter extends WindowAdapter
{ 
     public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
     {
         System.exit(0);
     }
}
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем героизм использования AWT, а не Swing или JavaFX?

Comment: @pinguin, по условию нужно использовать компоненты AWT

Answer (score 0):

У объекта `Frame` есть метод `setBackground`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setBackground(java.awt.Color)

используйте его в слушателе кнопки

```
public MyKeyAdapter2(AppWindow appWindow)
{
    this.appWindow = appWindow;
}

public void keyTyped (KeyEvent k)
{
    appWindow.setBackground(цвет);
}
}
```

При создании окна, добавьте в него кнопку и повесьте на неё этого слушателя

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    AppWindow appwin = new AppWindow();
    appwin.setSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
    appwin.setTitle("Blank window");
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.addListener(new MyKeyAdapter2(appwin));
    appwin.add(button);
    appwin.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: спасибо, появляется кнопка, но она просто серая, как получить случайный цвет?

Comment: ну тут придумайте свой алгоритм. Можете использовать рандомизатор (класс Random), исходя из выданного числа задать цвет. Можете создать массив цветов и из него выбирать любой. Можете рандомом выбирать числа от 0 до 255 и из них собирать цвет, на ваш вкус и цвет =)

Comment: спасибо вам за помощь

Comment: @oyashi если у вас не осталось вопросов, закройте вопрос.